# Is there way to download a pdf from sharepoint that has the download function turned off?

Tags: pdf, download, file-download

I have view only access to some pdf's on Microsoft Sharepoint. I want to download these PDFs. Downloading is turned off for me so I can't download the file like I normally would. Is there a workaround? I've tried to look in inspect elements already and the only document I can locate is simply one that leads to the same sharepoint viewer page again.

Comment: view only access in say google docs (no download possible) is acheived by server converting PDF into images and thus the client is NOT accessing the PDF or a downloadable file but simply seeing smoke through mirrors. FireFox uses a similar method in its PDF.js renderings of image background with html text overlaid as invisible but selectable for search etc. Technically not a real PDF viewer but a LOOKalike one. Inspect the PDF view and drill down, is it one single object per doc or one per page.